# Can I overwrite a CSS #ID with a class?

Tags: css, class, overwrite

I'm using a js-widget from a ticket service (OK-Ticket). The container of this widget has an ID, which is generated dynamically. Something like

```
<li class="okticket">
    <div id="ok_5134e2847ffe8">
        // The widget stuff
    </div>
</li>
```

Of course I can't overwrite the styles with

```
.okticket div {
    margin:0;
}
```

I could use !important, but everybody tells you: "Don't use !important". Isn't it the only way to go here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an ID to the `.okticket div`, then, make the CSS `#okdiv div {}`;

In CSS #ID + Selector is more important than just #ID

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/enapupe/WkwDH/

Answer (score 1):

Don't use !important is in one place. These situation can be considered for a good use of that.

Another way, you can use same #id selector and write your own styles. 
One more way, use parent class and #id as descendant selector - this will also override the original #id rules.

No need to write inline or important!

Comment: He said he has no access to the ok_xxxx div.. so, it comes from the host this way, with some kind of random id..
I don't see any problems using !important there.

Comment: True @enapupe, in that case !important is the way to go.

Comment: Then I will use !important. I never understood, why to not use it.

Comment: Not to use '!important' is just because it adds way too much specificity to a particular rule. Nothing such fancy here.

Answer (score 0):

The other way is using style attribute in html

```
<li class="okticket">
    <div id="ok_5134e2847ffe8" style="margin:0">
        // The widget stuff
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

In that case change places of class and id because the last one overrides the class properties.